# Why does running gradlew in a non-interactive bash session closes the session's stdin?

Tags: linux, bash, gradle, posix

I've noticed this strange issue of scripts exiting successfully early in a CI system when using `gradlew`. The following steps help outline this.

1. Create a file called `script` with the contents:

   ```
   ./gradlew
   echo DONE
   ```
2. Get a random `gradlew` from somewhere
3. Run `cat script | bash`

Notice that DONE never appears

AFAICT, running bash non-interactively causes the `exec java blah` at the end of `gradlew` to somehow allow java to close stdin and never allow the `echo DONE` to be read from the script being read in via stdin from `cat`. Supporting facts of this are:

- Changing the script to `./gradlew; echo DONE` will print DONE
- Replacing `./gradlew` with `./gradlew < /dev/null` will print DONE

Comment: Hi @edaniels. I'm reading your question again and I see I didn't take into account your second fact when you say `./gradlew < /dev/null` will print DONE. Is that correct? DONE **shouldn't** be printed there in my opinion...

Comment: It does in that case. I think your answer is correct and that this still holds. In both cases here, bash forks and the fork maintains the stdin in the normal case but with the redirection it's to devnull meaning Gradle has no chance to capture anything as it gets EOF immediately. If however you source the script instead of allow bash to execute via fork/exec, the exec in gradle should still be using the same stdin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an `exec something` somewhere (within `gradlew` in your case), you are replacing the current process image (`bash`) with something else (`java`).

From `help exec`:

> exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments ...]] [redirection ...]
>       Replace the shell with the given command.

**So the problem is not that *stdin* is getting closed, what is happening is that the new process (`java`) will be the one reading that input (*"echo DONE"*) and probably doing nothing with it.**

---

#### Explanation with example

Consider this script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Hello
exec cat
echo World
```

If you execute it providing some input for `cat`:

```
$ ./script.sh <<< "Nice"
Hello
Nice
```

You may expect also the word **World** be printed on the screen... WRONG!
Here nothing happens because anything else is executed after the `exec` command.

Now, if you pipe the script to bash:

```
$ cat script.sh | bash
Hello        <- bash interpreted "echo Hello" and printed Hello
echo World   <- cat read "echo World" and printed it (no interpertation ocurred)
```

Here you can clearly see the *process image replacement* in action.